# How to determine if client or agent hung up?

Tags: linux, asterisk, linphone, elastix, elastix-itk

I have an **elastix server4**, but I have a big problem. I don't know how to find who hung up the call  (agent or client).

How do I determine if client or agent hung up?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way do it via web without custom context writing.

Only thing you can do is setup failover destination for queue.

Maybe there are some info in CEL log, however that should be checked.